# "There was no such thing as ... " + "nor were there..."? "Or..."? "Nor... ?"

Tags: prepositions

I would like to convey two ideas in a single sentence.

Idea 1: "Rock music" was not (yet) an established music genre at some point in time

Idea 2: There were no more than a handful of songs with a backbeat at this same point in time

Are any of the following sentences correct?

1. "There was no such thing as 'Rock music' at this point, nor were there more than a handful of songs with a backbeat"
2. "There was no such thing as 'Rock music' at this point, nor more than a handful of songs with a backbeat"
3. "There was no such thing as 'Rock music' at this point, or more than a handful of songs with a backbeat"

I know that "no ..." is supposed to be followed by "or ...," but with the "no such thing" part, I am a bit lost.

Answer (score 0):

Number 1 and 2 are correct. I think 3 is viable, but sound less natural.

By ‘no’ you mean ‘neither were’, meaning it would be ‘neither were there more than a handful  of songs with a backbeat’. You could also use ‘or’ because using ‘or’ you are referring to the first part, being ‘There was no…’.

It doesn’t inverse, it negates.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Just to make it clear, are you sure you did not mean "By 'noR' you mean 'neither were'"? The "nor" answers do sound more natural to me too, but most grammatical sites seem to indicate that if the second part of the sentence is a noun phrase--which I thought was the case here--then "or" should be used. I may have got a bit confused.

Comment: @Miles I did not mean use neither were, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: No problem! But I am still confused! Did you mean 1/ "By 'no' you mean 'neither was,' meaning it would be 'neither was there such a thing as rock music at this point," or 2/ "By 'noR' you mean 'neither were,' meaning it would be 'neither were there more than a handful of songs with a backbeat"? I may be wrong but in your initial answer, the two parts of your reasoning don't seem to match.

Comment: @Miles now that I think of it, my example was very confusing.  Due to the way English works, it would vary depending on the rest of the sentence, so to be honest my example wan't the best.

Comment: No problem, thanks for trying to help me. It is also very possible that my sentence was needlessly complicated! I guess I will post a new question put more simply